# checkbox error in editing using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I just wanted to share my problem regarding checkbox here, because i know many can help me here. i have an array of checkboxes named skills[] and i stored the checked checkbox in a single column in my database because this is an application form project. I use `implode()` to separate the skills selected in the database by:

```
$skills = implode(',',$skills);
```

now this is my real problem because I don't have any idea how to retrieve the checked checkboxes in the database because whenever i will try to edit my checked checkbox. nothing in the checkboxes are checked even though the values are in the database.

the php code for getting the value of skills:

```
$skills = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT skills FROM php_employee_skills WHERE id=13");
            if($skills!=null){
                foreach($skills as $value):
                    $skills=$value->skills;
endforeach;
            }else{
                echo"<div class='updated' style='height:50px; font-size:12px;'>"."<br>".$message." in table skills in database"."</div>";
            }
```

I dont have any idea what to put here in my html code to retrieve the data:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" Value="C# Java" class="cbox">C# Java</td>
```

note: the skills in the application form which is in the form of checkbox are more than 10 so i use implode to save them in my database. is it right to use implode or explode in the situation of my application form?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$str="php,mysql,java";

$skills=explode(",",$str);

//print_r($str2);

foreach ($skills as $chk)
{
    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$chk.'">'. $chk."\n";
}
```

Comment: so you want to save the skills first in the array and retrieve them using explode? what i want to output is when i checked the java, php and other skills and i want to edit or check more skills then the previous skills should be checked already but what is happening is that there are mo checked skills when i edit the skills. hope you get my point :)

Answer (score 0):

Add **checked** attribute for checked checkbox

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" Value="C# Java" class="cbox" checked>C# Java</td>
```

that's no problem if you working only in the checkbox. but if you trying to list who have specified "skill" in database, you should separate them.

Comment: what do you mean by "separate them"? so you mean that implode is not applicable in this case? btw, thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $skills != null ) {
    foreach ( $skills as $skill) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Please make sure you read about [coding standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards) in WP. It can improve your code to follow them.

Now, the next problem ist that you need a way to identify your skill:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="C# Java" class="cbox" <?php echo (in_array('C# Java', $skills) ? 'checked' : '' )  ?> /> C# Java</td>
```

In this line, you check if the skill is in your skillset. If so, you add the **checked** attribute, else nothing happens.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried your comment 

    global $wpdb;
    $skills = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT skills FROM php_employee_skills WHERE id=13");
  if($skills !=null){
  $skills = explode(',',$skills);
  foreach ($skills as $skill){
  echo 'input type="checkbox" name= "skills[]" value = "C# Java" '; 
  echo (in_array('C# Java', $skills) ? 'checked' : '' ) ;
  }
  
  }

the output is: Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, and  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

hope you can still continue to help me out :)

Comment: Obviously, skills is already a array. Uncomment the line `$skills = explode(',', $skills);`

Comment: First check by echo $skills before if($skills !=null) condition.

Comment: @Antony, the $skills output Array. literally the word Array.

Comment: Yes because of that it showing the - expects parameter 2 to be string warning. Can you give me an example data which is stored in skills column for id 13 and how you are listing all the skills for user end?

Comment: @Antony in order to see the file type of $skills a `var_dump($skills` would've been a much better choice. Thats why i meant to remove, not uncomment, the line `$skills = explode(',', $skills);`. I will update my answer.

Comment: the of skills with a skillsid of 13 are C#/JAVA,TURBO C/CTT,VB.NET. that values are from the checkbox. if i want to edit the skills C#/JAVA,TURBO C/CTT,VB.NET should be checked to track the previous data but when i click edit C#/JAVA,TURBO C/CTT,VB.NET are not checked.

Comment: Create a fiddle for that so we can actually see the code and its contents. Otherwise, it is hard to assist you further.